# building in an if statement into a mysqli search

Tags: php, if-statement, mysqli

I built an ad system for my website that first tries to find a specific ad based on location and category.  Failing that it picks only based on location, failing that it picks a generic ad:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM ads WHERE city='$city' AND category='$category' LIMIT 1";
$user_query = mysqli_query($db_conx, $sql);

if( mysqli_num_rows($user_query)==0){
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM ads WHERE city='$city' AND category='All' LIMIT 1";
    $user_query = mysqli_query($db_conx, $sql);

if( mysqli_num_rows($user_query)==0){ // 'City' is the generic all locations
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM ads WHERE city='City' AND category='All' LIMIT 1";
    $user_query = mysqli_query($db_conx, $sql);
    }
}
```

I thought it might be possible to write a single mysqli statement to do all 3 operations, but nothing seemed to work properly. (I tried using various versions of union and limit 1).
Is it possible to do something like this, or is it best left as is?

Comment: You'd probably do better to create one SQL stored procedure to work out the logic rather than going back and forth between Application and Database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM ads WHERE city='$city' AND category='$category' 
        UNION
        SELECT * FROM ads WHERE city='$city' AND category='All'
        UNION
        SELECT * FROM ads WHERE city='City' AND category='All' LIMIT 1";
$user_query = mysqli_query($db_conx, $sql);
```

Just let MySQL do the dirty work

Answer (score 1):

I'd solve this using a [CASE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/case.html):

```
SELECT *, CASE
 WHEN city='$city' AND category='$category' THEN 1
 WHEN city='$city' THEN 2
 WHEN category='$category' THEN 3
 ELSE 4
END as rating
FROM ads
WHERE city IN('$city', 'All') AND category IN('$category', 'All')
ORDER BY rating ASC
```

This is more flexible then a UNION and allows you to tweak the priority

Comment: I have never seen CASE before.  Looks interesting, I'll have to check it out.